# (Codeigniter) next_prev_url calendar with ajax or j-query

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, calendar

i want my next_prev_url calendar become to ajax
so if i press the next or prev link my calendar will process in ajax...
this is my controller

```
$this->load->model('tasks_koord_model');
    $prefs = array (
        'show_next_prev'    => TRUE,
        'next_prev_url'     => site_url('kalender_koord_controller/index'),
        'template'          =>'{table_open}<table class="calendar">{/table_open}
    {week_day_cell}<th class="day_header">{week_day}</th>{/week_day_cell}
    {cal_cell_content}<div class="event"><a href="{content}"><span class="day_listing">{day}</span></a></div>{/cal_cell_content}
    {cal_cell_content_today}<div class="today"><a href="{content}"><span class="day_listing">{day}</span></a></div>{/cal_cell_content_today}
    {cal_cell_no_content}<span class="day_listing">{day}</span>&nbsp;{/cal_cell_no_content}
    {cal_cell_no_content_today}<div class="today"><span class="day_listing">{day}</span></div>{/cal_cell_no_content_today}'
    );
    $this->load->library('calendar',$prefs);
```

please help me...

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you're looking for. https://thecodingmaniac.blogspot.com/ see attached file below. Hope this helps.